# CSS zoom out makes div expand

Tags: css, width, zooming, expand

My problem is the zoom out function in the Chrome. I have no problem with IE, but Chrome makes my menus expand and I dont know why. Probably the pixel values cause this but need for help, thanks.

Look at the menu with black background and the other menu on Chrome and don't forget to zoom out until it is 33% or 25%.

Edit: If I give a value to the "li" element, the menu doesn't expand, but i can't give a value to the "li".

You can look at

```
   <!-- menu -->
     <div id="menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>

    </ul>
     </div>
    <!-- menu -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2cfaT/1/

Comment: Possibly related: Is it really worth worrying about tiny zoom?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391394/worth-styling-zoomed-out/18391463#18391463

Comment: @yochannah I know nobody zoom that level, but font-size looks like getting bigger even if I use em,%.
Just wondering why does this happen?